# If $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$, then $f(x)=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function $k$ times differentiable, with $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$, for any $t,x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $$f(x)=\dfrac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$$
For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

I don't have any clue how to start to prove this.
Any leads? (Please try to not give answers lol)

Comment: Even without the $k$-time differentiability condition, the assumption that $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$ for all $t,x\in\Bbb R$ already implies that $f$ is $k$-time differentiable, and so $f(x)=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if you differentiate the relation $f(tx) = t^k f(x)$ with respect to $t$ ?

Comment: Got it! Thank you!