# If $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$ , then $f(x)=\frac{f^k(0)}{k!}x^k,∀x\in\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the same question as this link here: [If $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$, then $f(x)=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365676/if-ftx-tkfx-then-fx-fracfk0kxk-forall-x-in-mathbbr)

But I can't comment, and my only option is "answer", but I don't want to "answer" a question.

My question is: "I didn't understand what it implies. If I differentiate $\frac{t^k}{k!}f(x)$ with respect to $t$ k-times I will get $\frac{k!}{k!} f(x)\rightarrow f(x)$.

But in the given example, I can't really grasp it. Why $\frac{f^k(0)}{k!}x^k$ equals any given function? Which function should I differentiate? I don't see why it should be $t^k$. And why there is a $x^k$ multiplying $\frac{f^k(0)}{k!}$.
Thanks in advance."

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$ is an identity in both $t$ and $x$...

$$ f(tx)=t^kf(x) \implies \frac {d^k}{dt^k}f(tx)=f(x)\frac{d^k}{dt^k}t^k$$

So
$$ x^kf^{(k)}(tx) = k! f(x)$$
The result follows when $t=0$